# Access a URL via json, which can be opened in chrome by providing User/Pass

Tags: javascript, json, http, security, authentication

I can open an API url in chrome by going to some address like:

`http://some-path-to-server.com/myapi/`
and it asks for a user/pw
[image]

After logging in I can see the json response. Question is how can I get that json via $.getJSON api call in my localhost server? Or how I can dig it out that extra params I need to send in my getJSON call.

Comment: Check the network tab of the browser developer tools. Make sure it's set to _not_ clear logs on page load and try accessing the page. Given that you're seeing that login prompt, it's almost certainly using basic HTTP authorization: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme

Answer (score 0):

Just call `$.getJSON` api in your javascript.

```
function getJson(){
    $.getJSON("your url", function(data){
      alert("JSON Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
```

**Upd:** You can add authorization info in headers like below code. Or using `beforeSend` function to add extra info to headers.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "your url",
      dataType: "json",
      headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer 5c530532-f39c-4f22-b48c-e226f8d08405"
      },
      success: function(result) {
          console.log(result);
      }
})
```

Comment: 401 authorization failed

Comment: You should add authorization info in http header.